# Laravel routes not defined when trying to link my buttons

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to route my webpages to route to buttons but when I do I get a
Route `[views/b2b.blade.php] not defined. (View: /home/bobtheknob/example-app-2/resources/views/test.blade.php)` 
I have tried different routing methods and b2b and /b2b but I keep getting the same error.

`Route::get('views/b2b.blade.php', function (){ return  'b2b';  });`
This is my route

`<button> <a href="{{route('views/b2b.blade.php') }}" >Business-to-business</a> </button>`

And these are the routes I am using for my buttons
If you can give me any help that would be appreciated I’ve already watched and read guides and they didn’t give me the answer I was looking for.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define routes in Laravel, you specify the URL path/structure you would like to capture and a callback to perform when the route is accessed. Using your scenario, it looks like you're trying to capture `/b2b`. Therefore in your `routes/web.php` file you would do the following:

```php
Route::get('/b2b', function () {
    return view('b2b');
})->name('b2b');
```

The above defines our route and informs Laravel to return the `b2b` view (`resources/views/b2b.blade.php` - you can omit the `.blade.php` segments when calling views) whenever someone accesses the route.

The `->name('b2b')` function at the end informs Laravel that we want to be able to access the route in our code by the name `b2b`. This is done using the [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) helper method. As an example using your scenario:

```html
<a href="{{ route('b2b') }}">Business 2 Business</a>
```

Alternatively you could use the [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url) helper which takes the URL you want to generate a link for:

```html
<a href="{{ url('/b2b') }}">Business 2 Business</a>
```

To understand more about routing and Laravel in general, I suggest you take time to watch/read some tutorials, the [Laravel 8 from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) series would be a good staring point.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help was looking at Laravel 6 from scratch will look at Laravel 8 instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass route name to `route` method

```
Route::get('views/b2b.blade.php', function (){ return  'b2b';  })->name("b2b");

<button> <a href="{{route('b2b') }}" >Business-to-business</a> </button>
```